Python Web scraping con Beautifulsoup e request_html no muestra todos los datos
Buen día, estoy tratando de extraer datos de este sitio web: https://bodysolid-europe.com/collections/all mediante web scraping con las librerías BeautifulSoup, requests y requests html, adjunto el código:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
response = session.get('https://bodysolid-europe.com/collections/all')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

ul_items = soup.find_all('ul', class_='product-list')
for ul in ul_items:
title = ul.find('a', class_='product-item-title').text
price = ul.find(class_='price').text

print([title, price])

Al momento de correr el código solo me muestra los datos de un solo elemento, el primero de la lista:
[D:urllib3.connectionpool] Starting new HTTPS connection (%d): %s:%s
[D:urllib3.connectionpool] %s://%s:%s "%s %s %s" %s %s
['Best Fitness Ab Board BFAB10', '�199.00']

[Done] exited with code=0 in 1.076 seconds

No sé que es lo que sucede, ya le instalé y actualicé un buen de librerías, lo he intentado mediante diferentes métodos, como xpath, pero muestra pocos datos, lo máximo que llego a extraer fueron 16 (cuando la página tiene más de 500 items), casi siempre mostraba la siguiente salida:
[D:urllib3.connectionpool] Starting new HTTPS connection (%d): %s:%s
[D:urllib3.connectionpool] %s://%s:%s "%s %s %s" %s %s[D:asyncio] Using proactor: %s
[D:websockets.client] = connection is CONNECTING
[D:websockets.client] > GET %s HTTP/1.1
[D:websockets.client] > %s: %s
[D:websockets.client] > %s: %s
[D:websockets.client] > %s: %s
[D:websockets.client] > %s: %s
[D:websockets.client] > %s: %s
[D:websockets.client] > %s: %s
[D:websockets.client] > %s: %s
[D:websockets.client] < HTTP/1.1 %d %s

Si pudieran ayudarme a encontrar cual es el problema con todo eso lo agradecería demasiado.

Ten en cuenta que Requests simplemente permite enviar peticiones  GET, POST, PUT, HEAD, etc  a un servidor y recibir su respuesta, si el contenido necesita ser generado dinámicamente en el lado del cliente, si se necesita  de la ejecución de JS, requests no te va a ser útil, en este caso lo más simple suele ser usar selenium y emular un navegador completo.
